# Two files with the exactly same content. One of them gives me 52 hbox overfull, the other zero

Tags: boxes, bad-box

I'm really puzzled. I spent hours and hours starting a special pocket book configuration, font sizes, margins (almost zero), headers and footers...

I debugged all the hbox and vbox overfull and underfull. Until I got the only message I'm satisfied:

- 0 errors, 0 warnings, 0 badboxes, figure 1:

[image: 0 errors, 0 warnings, 0 badboxes]

Then I wrote 3 chapters, with 4 sections, of course, still tweaking when needed, until I got satisfied with the "sample version" of the book.

This sample version will be sent for free, while I write the other chapters and sections. So I decided to "freeze" the tex as is, call it another file name, while I work on the other.

I just, I swear to you, I just copied the file with another name.  You can see the names and the errors in the images below:

The original gives no badboxes. I opened the new file in another "tab" in KILE editor (debian/linux) and compiled, and surprised I saw:

- 0 errors, 0 warnings, 52 badboxes, figure 2:

[image: 0 errors, 0 warnings, 52 badboxes]

I've tried everything now. I've read all questions here and in other sites. I've tried:

- cleaning auxiliary files
- adding code to the preamble:
- the obvious:

```
\hbadness=10000 % more than 10000 supress all warnings underfull hbox badness
\vbadness=10000 % more than 10000 supress all warnings underfull hbox badness
```

- from other questions here:

```
\raggedbottom
\vbadness=\maxdimen
```

- tip from another site

```
\usepackage{microtype}
```

- changing lower spaces:

```
 \usepackage{setspace}
 \setstretch{0.15}
```

- changing fuzz and other variables:

```
 \hfuzz=20pt
 \vfuzz=20pt
 \overfullrule=0pt
 \emergencystretch20pt   % More blank space to put in to lines
 \tolerance10000          % value for degree of inadequate line filling
 \setlength{\emergencystretch}{3em}
```

- doing this trick to set the number of lines:

```
 \setlength{\dimen0}{\textheight}
 \addtolength{\dimen0}{-\topskip}
 \divide\dimen0\baselineskip
 \setlength{\textheight}{\number\dimen0 \baselineskip}
 \addtolength{\textheight}{\topskip}
```

- Changing font size to test

All to no avail. Besides, the file should be exactly the same. I even was so astonished that I thought the "copy" command failed, then I just "control-a / control-c" in the old file's tab window in kile and "control-a control-v" in the new tab, to be sure I had the exact same file.

I can still compile the old file with no badboxes. But the new file has this 52 badboxes that doesn't seem to diminish.

Some of the options above gave me some hope. Changing font size to a greater one gives me 67 badboxes. Using `setstretch` got me to 48. And I think that is about it.

Seriously, I don't care about the warnings in the sense that I would need to change the wording or insert a newline here and there. I just want the warnings to disappear (and the text to be the same).

Thanks any help.

Comment: Yes, same machine @egreg. Same everything. Same directory, so it sees the same subdirectory where the images are

Comment: Sure thing. Let me do that and report back. I also "include" c sources with the lstlistings package and a "reference.tex" at the end. Maybe the last tex needs to "recompile" as well?

Comment: Diff show nothing different, appart from those commented lines quoted in the question, of attempts to try to solve the problems.

Comment: I just opened both logs. 2000 lines. Where do you want me to put it? Maybe "pastebin" site or something?

Comment: Sorry, I might need to do the second file log again. It is with microtype package. The original doesn't have it. I'll create the exact file again and generate just the second log.

Comment: the overfull message clearly shows the file name: `benante2019_linguagem_C_exercicios_resolvidos_amostra`. You are using it somewhere.

Comment: can it be the package "underline" to allow me to write "things_like_this" without need to type "things\\_like\\_this" that messed up?

Comment: * sorry, package "underscore", not "underline". I just checked. I removed it and compiled again. Same 52 errors in the file with big name. No errors in the others.

Comment: you are presumably putting the filename in the page head? since it is showing the filename as overfull while the output is active

Comment: Hi @DavidCarlisle. The filename for the backup was completely arbitrary. The original file, that I worked for days, is not inside any files, headers, nothing. Then I decided to make a copy of it with another name, I even added a word at the end that I never thought before, "amostra", that means "sample". So, no, I didn't use the filename of the backup anywhere. But somehow some packages may refer to the name. And since the page is really small (9cm x 12cm), latex thinks the filename don't fit. But again: I never used the filename in the contents of the files (let alone the backuped filename)!

Comment: Ok, for curiosity, I went all bersek and kept removing/commenting all packages out, one by one. Two packages dropped the number of warnings from 52 to 48, but not enough. I kept going and going. I removed ALL packages except `geometry` and `crop`. When I remove any of these, the numbers of warnings drop to zero. But that is not much, since they probably just allow a big page, of course. But that solved the mystery, I guess. These two packages don't like big filenames... Or... Ok, I have another test to try: small page without these 2 packages.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You provided no test file but you are getting the filename in an overfull box on every page and you mentioned you are using crop so I assume you have

[image]

with the filename on every page from

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[paperwidth=5cm,paperheight=5cm,pdftex=false]{geometry}
\usepackage[a4,pdftex,center]{crop}
\begin{document}
\crop[cam,info]


fooo

\clearpage

baaar

\end{document}
```

If you make the page small enough or the filename long enough, it will not fit in the space.

Note here that I am setting a small logical page size (5cm wide) on a larger actual page (A4) if you specify the same page size then crop will put the crop corners at the physical corners of the page so the info block will be off the top of the page, although tex still "prints" it, and it will still be reported as overfull if too wide, even though it will be cropped by your pdf viewer and not shown.

Comment: I think you solve the mystery. As you provided much more insight than my own answer, I'll accept yours. Thanks

Comment: Is there an option to crop to not write the filename?

Comment: @DrBeco  use `noinfo` instead of `info`, see the crop manual, but why use crop at all? do you need it?

Comment: Not really. It was a hack. I need the small lines draw in the border, only. That is because the ereader I'm testing moves the text to the center of the page if the page has just one small paragraph and all blank. But with border, it honors the text position. I tried fancybox but it is too ugly. Crop is simple and almost invisible. I also have another solution at work. (Next comment)

Comment: @DrBeco there really was litle mysery even just from the initial screenshot of the warning it was clear that you were putting the filename in the page heading, that that was from crop rather than from fancyhdr settings was deduced later from comments as you didn't put that information in the question.

Comment: To keep the page with some printable text above and below, so the main text of the page don't move, I used a nice line above in the header, and a simple page number below, ver near the edge (since the ereader adds margin on its own, I can work without margin). But I still have problems in pages that I do not want page numbers. Maybe I will print something like a `\_`, but it is ugly. If only it honored an invisible space

Comment: @DrBeco I don't understand the comment to be honest as the printing of the page body and the position of the text within it is not affected by any text or rules you put in the page head and foot but if you want to print something invisible perhaps `\mbox{ }` is what you are looking for although I can not guess where this would be needed. oh the info viewer not tex moves the page.. I see.., OK, so why not just use a ruled page style in fancyhdr?

Comment: I'll experiment with `\mbox{ }`, thanks. If anything, I'll write another question, as this would be a different subject. But I think I got it now. Will see. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

I don't know exactly what the implications are, but from my tests, removing and commenting all packages, I got this results:

Total of 52 warnings referring the filename being to big to fit the page, even that I never wrote it on the contents of the book.

Removing package and results follow as:

- package import : less 2 warnings
- package include : less 2 warning
- package lstlisting: less 8 warnings
- package fancyhdr: less 6 warnings
- package crop: warnings goes to zero. Re-adding and removing next.
- package geometry: warnings goes to zero. Re-adding and and trying something else.

Next I decided to set the page to the original size without the `geometry` package, to check it. The page is 9cm x 12cm, but I figured `a7paper` would do. Class `book` won't accept it, but class `scrbook` did.

- Removing `geometry` and setting the page size with:

  `\documentclass[a7paper,10pt,openany]{scrbook}` : total warnings citing the filename is 62 now.
- Removing finally the last package, `crop`. Warnings drops to zero.

**Final configuration:** no packages at all, just `a7paper`, no warnings. Adding package `crop` gives warning about filename size not fitting.

**Weird conclusion:** in a small page, with a big filename, package `crop` gives warnings of *badbox* about the filename, even though the filename was never written inside the document.

Comment: The count of warnings is completely meaningless, what matters is what the warnings say, and you haven't shown any log file.

Comment: By default crop does write the filename on every page

Comment: Log files are linked in the comments below the question. But during my tests I was not only "counting" warning messages, but I was also disregarding the ones that did not mention the file name.

Comment: "By default crop does write the filename on every page" @DavidCarlisle . That will definitely solve the mystery

Comment: @DrBeco as I mentioned  those links to the full logs are not usable (blacklisted site)

Comment: Ok. Sorry about that, @DavidCarlisle . I only used external links after asking permission in the comment, to avoid 2000 lines of log in the question. If there is another good solution, I'd like to know to where to put those ugly log files. Maybe I should have used "pastebin" site after all. Sprunge is a nice tool though. It is a shame it is blocked for you. I can simple do a linux command `cat filename.log | sprunge` and get a nice URL to share. Very useful indeed.

Comment: @DrBeco probably enough people did that to share files that were not tex log files that it flipped a switch, but to be honest _any_ external link is bad here. Your question and any posted answers are archived _forever_ by this site but unless you can promise the same of pastebin or sprunge links then future readers will find it hard to understand. If the log file fits in the 30000 character link add it to the question, if it does not, then you can almost always make your example file smaller so it does.